# Geofence calculating new longitude, latitude from distance and bearing (Python - Library)

Tags: python, google-maps, mapping, distance

I need to create a set of Lat/Long to define a geofence zone, I have a central point (LatX, LongX) and I want to provide a distance (Miles) and distance (Degrees) and then get the new position (LatY, LongY).

I have some examples but there do not take into account potential N/S and E/W , is there a python library that can be used to to provide these new positions based on a distance and angle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is! Try:
https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#module-geopy.distance

```
pip install geopy
```

Example code:

```
from geopy import distance, location

london = location.Point(51.5074, 0.1278)
paris = location.Point(48.8566, -2.3522)

brighton = distance.geodesic().destination(
    point=london,
    bearing=180,
    distance=distance.Distance(kilometers=76))

print("london-paris:", distance.distance(london, paris).kilometers)
print("brighton-paris:", distance.distance(brighton, paris).kilometers)
```

prints

```
london-paris: 343.9231200909896
brighton-paris: 282.31635799139883
```